# Script javascript width ignored iPhone 6. Why?

Tags: javascript, iphone, width, screen-size, mobile-browser

I'm having a problem with a script that randomize 2 arrays codes when I try to change its behaviour with a width condition (at least, on iPhone6). Basically, I want to alternate 2 ads... but when screen is less than 850px, I wanna only show one

```
<script>
    function random_ad(){
        var ads = [];

        //1st Ad
        ads[0] = 'iframe code';
        //2nd Ad
        ads[1] = 'a-img code';

        var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;

        if (screenWidth < 850) {
            //Ads[0] = ads[1]
            ads[0] = '2nd ad code';
        }

        var ry = Math.floor(Math.random()*ads.length);
        document.write(ads[ry]);

    }

    random_ad();
</script>`
```

Of course, I can organize this code in other way, but it looks the problem is that iPhone6 device (at least) is ignoring this condition: if (screenWidth < 850).

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compare pixel-density?

iPhone rescales it's screen, so you need to be more precise (at least it has to be like that in css):

```
if (screenWidth < 850 && window.devicePixelRatio == 2) {}
```